# php define('') for multilingual page

Tags: php

Website may have more than one language. I see 2 options how to echo necessary text depending on language

First option (I always used this option).

index.php

```
if($language == 'russian'){
include_once('russian.php');
}
echo $title;
```

russian.php

```
$title = 'текст по-русски';
```

Second option (now see such option in one code)

index.php

```
if($language == 'russian'){
include_once('russian.php');
}
echo TITLE;
```

russian.php

```
define('TITLE', 'текст по-русски');
```

Is the second option better (may be performance)? Or no difference?

Comment: I see more options: gettext. It's specialised for the task of i18n and comes with the tools you need for the right workflow. Believe me, you don't even know how complex the workflow for i18n is.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel? deceze has the right suggestion here.